# Wrong result when use string.decode("utf-8","ignore")

Tags: python, string, decode

I'm doing code with string.decode() as below:

```
 original_data = cipher1.decrypt(plaintext1)
 print(original_data)
 original_data_1 = original_data.decode("utf-8", "ignore")
 print(original_data_1)
```

And the result as: [image]

```
b'{"ID":"N1","a":23,"b":72,"c":5}\x00\xf5&V\xb7\x18r-\xb4\xc1J\x1e\r\xd5#q\xc9'
#qID":"N1","a":23,"b":72,"c":5}&Vr-J
```

when the first line is value of original_data and the second is original_data_1.
The problem occurred when the first two bytes as **{"** decoded as **#q**
Could you tell me why I got this problem and how to solve.
I want **{"** decoded utf-8 as **{"** exactly.
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Can you paste the actual byes and string into the question rather than an image so we can try to reproduce your problem?

Comment: That's Ok.
b'{"ID":"N1","a":23,"b":72,"c":5}\x00\xf5&V\xb7\x18r-\xb4\xc1J\x1e\r\xd5#q\xc9'            

#qID":"N1","a":23,"b":72,"c":5}&Vr-J
the former is bytearray and the latter is the decoded string.

Comment: So it's probably not 'utf-8' encoding. I tried 'latin-1' and that didn't work. 'utf-16' renders what looks like chinese characters... do you have any idea what encoding it could be?

Comment: Sorry guys. I have tried this code and it worked. I guess It's a system problem of my Raspberry Pi 3B+. I tried several times but it worked time to time. It's exactly utf-8 but I don't know why It sometimes went wrong.
b'{"ID":"N1","a":23,"b":73,"c":5}\x00\xca\t\x1f-\xa1i\xfcD=\x1f!\xcfDo\x91\xc5'
{"ID":"N1","a":23,"b":73,"c":5} -iD=!Do

Comment: Maybe you've got a data corruption problem on the device. How are you reading in this data? Is it on an SD card or... how?

Comment: No. I did receive the encrypted messeges through RF and try to decrypt them. But the problem only occurs with this block of code.